# Can't catch click on group item ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I created ExpandableListView and Group item with Child item to this List:

MainActivity.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ExpandableListView 
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearActivity>
```

GroupItem.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="25dp"/>  

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="ToMachine"
        android:src="@drawable/right_connect"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't catch click on Group item, only on button. I create simple way handler to list

```
//      List.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener(){
//
//          @Override
//          public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
//                  int groupPosition, long id) {
//              return true;
//          }});
```

Comment: can you explain more about the issue

Comment: I added image button to Group item of ExpandableListView, after that I can't catch click on Group indicator.

Comment: @user1711993 - can you please elaborate : you want click event only on the button of group Item, not in the whole item.. or something else.

Comment: Thanks for replay you all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this out set  `android:focusable` to `true` in XML and in code set it to false. like this:

inside the view group

```
ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ibDeleteRecipe);
        imgbutton .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                ...
            }
        });
        imgbutton .setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: I would like to point out that this also works for other controls (ViewPager, Webview). The reason is because of focusable controls so making them not focusable fixes it.